# How to get values of array by powershell from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

Defined double array:

```
double[] doubleArray = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0};
```

During debugging (VS2013) in "Package Manager Console" created varaible $doubleArray:

```
$doubleArray = $dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame.Locals | Where-Object {$_.name -Match "doubleArray"}
```

How can I get all **values** of the array via powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "value" is only a String:

[Capture VS local variables while debugging in EnvDTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467241/capture-vs-local-variables-while-debugging-in-envdte)

Obviosly there is nothing more to it than just that string. It looks like, before handing the result over to the PowerShell-Window a ToString() is done, so it is no longer an object that can be expanded.

```
PM> $doubleArray.value | Select *

Length
------
11
```

or:

```
PM> $doubleArray | Select value -ExpandProperty Value

{double[3]}
```

Comment: As I know, VS extension ObjectExporter can take values and export them. If it's possible from c#, probably it's possible from powershell too